# Show positiveness for a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, cauchy-problem

> Let $y(x)$ a $C^1$ function that solves the ODE
>
> \begin{cases}
> y'(x)= \sin(y(x)+x^2)\ \\
> y(0)=0
> \end{cases}
>
> i) Show that $y'(0)=y''(0)=0$, while $y'''(0)=2>0$
>
> ii) Show that $y(x)>0$ for every $x \in (0,\sqrt{\pi})$, while $y(x)<0$ for $x \in (-\sqrt{\pi},0)$.

---

My attempt:

i) I just wrote down the derivatives, I don't wrote the computations as they're easy.

ii) First, I compute the stationary solutions, i.e.

$$\sin(y(x)+x^2) = 0$$ therefore $y(x)=0$ and $y(x)=\pi-x^2$ are the stationary solutions. From $y''(0)=0$ I have that in $x=0$ the solution changes concavity.

Also, from existence and uniqueness, if in a right neigbourhood of $0$ the solution is positive, it will be still positive until $x= \sqrt{\pi}$ since at this point there's the intersetion of the parabola with the $x$-axis.

**I don't know how to use the fact that $y'''(0)>0$ in order to prove that in a right neigbourhood of $0$ the solution is positive**

How should I move?

Comment: Couldn't you use Taylor's series to show it is positive in a right neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: Thanks for the advice: yes indeed $y (\varepsilon) >0$ for $\varepsilon >0$, so it's positive. As $y''(0)=0$, in a left neigbourhood of $0$ it is negative. By existence and uniqueness, the solution must remain negative/positive if $x \in (-\sqrt{\pi},0)$ ($(0,\sqrt{\pi})$) respectively